# Plotting of an expression in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, expression

I want to plot the below expression using Mathematica:

$\begin{aligned} \operatorname{Pr}(e)_{C S} & \leq \frac{1}{2} e^{-M k N_S\left(\sqrt{N_B+1}-\sqrt{N_B}\right)^2}  \hspace{45pt} (1)\\ \end{aligned}$

with the following parameters:
$ M=10^5:10^7,\; N_S = 0.01, κ = 0.01, and\; N_B = 1$.
I have attempted to plot the curves, but I am encountering some challenges. The resulting plot does not match the expected outcome.

**Code:**

```
Pr[k_, Nb_, Ns_, M_] = 1/2*Exp[-M*k*Ns*(Sqrt[Nb + 1] - Sqrt[Nb])^2]
Plot[Log10@{Pr[0.01, 20, 0.01, M]}, {M, 10^5, 10^7},PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14], Axes -> True,GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True,TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], AxesLabel -> {"log_10(M)","log_10(Pr)"}]
```

Could you please assist me in creating the desired plot using Mathematica?

**My outcome:**

[image: My outcome:]

**Expected outcome (solid  blue curves):**

[image: Expected outcome (solid blue curves):]

Comment: Use `LogLogPlot[Pr[...], ...]`

Comment: @MarcoB: I tried, but not getting the appropriate result. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly doesn't work with LogLogPlot? I tried it in my answer below and the results seem in line with the figure you showed. Note that in your text you mentioned $N_b = 1$ but in your code you set $N_b$ to 20.

Comment: @MarcoB: LogLogPlot worked for me as well. I was getting an error because I mistakenly used "N" instead of "M," which is a protected symbol. Additionally, you are correct; it should indeed be Nb=20. Thank you for your assistance in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

"13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

Pr[k_, Nb_, Ns_, M_] =
  1/2*Exp[-M*k*Ns*(Sqrt[Nb + 1] - Sqrt[Nb])^2];

Plot[
 Log10@Pr[0.01, 20, 0.01, 10^M],
 {M, 5, 7},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14],
 Axes -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold],
 FrameLabel ->
  (StringForm["``(``)", Subscript["log", 10], #] & /@
    {HoldForm[M], HoldForm[Pr]}),
 Epilog -> {Style[Text[
     StringForm[
      "    κ\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]0.01\n  ``\[ThinSpace]=\
\[ThinSpace]0.01\n``\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]20",
      Subscript[N, S], Subscript[N, B]],
     Scaled@{0.25, 0.2}, {1, 0}], 14]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob Hanlon: Yes, this is precisely the outcome I was aiming for. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LogLogPlot`:

```
Clear[Pr]
Pr[k_, Nb_, Ns_, M_]:= 1/2*Exp[-M*k*Ns*(Sqrt[Nb + 1] - Sqrt[Nb])^2]

LogLogPlot[
  Pr[0.01, 20, 0.01, M], {M, 10^5, 10^7},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
  Axes -> True,GridLines -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True, TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]
]
```

[image]

That looks very similar to your desired output to me.